# What is the best way to create/deploy a full stack app with video Api

Tags: database, mongodb, video, deployment

I have been studying full stack development for the past few months , but my projects are mock-ups being deployed on sites like heroku and render.
A friend of mine wants me to make a blog for him and his coworkers , its a simple front end blog but they also want to be able to upload videos , so I 100% need an Api and some video saving way to get all those videos. The only option im aware of would be creating a back-end video saving server.

1. I dont know how to save videos on a database ( I use mongoDB)
2. I have never deployed an actual app with its own domain , never mind
   a whole backend app that would require some server hosting provider.

What is the best way to approach this ? Is there a video saving/deleting host where i can fetch all my videos with an API and use them for my blog page , is it easier with a back-end , honestly im clueless,but atleast from a curiosity perspective , what are your recommendations?

Comment: **(1)** If they want a blog, why don't they just use an existing free system like [WordPress](https://wordpress.com/create-blog/)? Unless you've reached a stage of having article/post templates and just need video? **(2)** You don't save video files in a database, you save their URL paths as text in a database, after uploading them to some storage server. Look for free storage or better look for free webspace (to test with) such as 000Webhost.com's free plan. That one allows PHP which you'd need if handling your own uploads.